# Using Garb with GA Management API v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, garb-gem

I installed Sija's fork of `garb` and am having some issues. The documentation appears to be a bit outdated as some things have been deprecated.

I have the following code (ignore the fact that it's horribly unsecure):

```
extend Garb::Model
metrics :pageviews
dimensions :page_path

Garb::Session.login('XXXXXX@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
profile = Garb::Management::Profile.all.detect { |p| p.web_property_id == 'UA-XXXXX-1' }
puts profile.visits
```

When I run this, I get undefined method `visits`. I also tried this code on [StackOverview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832106/how-to-test-google-analytics-garb-api-with-rspec), and it returned undefined method `results`. I'm guessing these are due to the new GA Management API v3 changes, but does anyone know the new way to access pageviews/visits?

I'm trying to query pageviews by date in the end.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class extending `Garb::Model` (https://github.com/Sija/garb#define-a-report-class). Btw, documentation has been updated to work with the newest version of the gem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
class Report 
  extend Garb::Model

  metrics     :pageviews
  dimensions  :pagePath 
end
```

Edit: Thanks for the edit! That was my first ever post :)